# Android Listview: Problem with its height, while dragging up

Tags: android, android-listview

Sorry for not having proper title to the question,

I have a list view that can implement drag and drop. It implements two directions, up and down. In down direction I have just given more height (60dp normal , more height is 120dp).

The list item contains a textview and an image view. The problem comes up when I drag up, I want to pass the same list height but instead of default behavior [List item grows downwards....] the list item should go upwards and it must have same 120dp height.

This is what happens [Downwards direction]

```
=========================
TextView


[*this denotes the height is 120dp downwards*]

=========================
```

This is what I want.[Upwards direction]

```
========================



[*this denotes the height is 120dp upwards*]

TextView
========================
```

How can it be possible?

Comment: A clarification - from what I gather, you want to be able to add new items to the top of the list. Also, as the list grows, the item at the bottom of the list stays where it is, and the vertical scrollbar decreases in size. Essentially a reverse ListView. Is that correct?

Comment: no mate.... sorry but you were not correct. I doesn't add or remove anything..... just rearrange the items with drag and drop.... Most of the times there isn't a scroll view at all......

Answer (score 0):

can you rephrase your question? what are your requirements? On a semi-related note, all motion events inside of a listview/scrollview are consumed by the scrolling view. It would be hard for you to drag items out of a listview.

Comment: problem is not dragging, problem is when the item of list view is given more height, it grows downwards, I want it to grow upwards based on some condition..........

Comment: @Prasham could you not allow it to grow downwards, and use a combination of moving the layout with visibilty="gone" and smoothScrollByOffset(int)? To give the perception is has expanded upwards

Comment: @Blundell smoothScrollByOffset is supported by api level 11 and i have to support api level 7..... I am not optimistic on this method

Comment: @Prash ah sorry but there are variants you could look at like setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y) API lvl 1 . not ideal I realise

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java;h=90b208a3ce69f2efcb28497770474fd66c6b8e73;hb=HEAD) implementation of drag and drop in Music app.

Comment: the link you provided is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can also get ideas from Mark Murphy's implementation: [cwac-touchlist](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist).